# Como seleciono apenas um elemento com uma classe que existem em outros elementos?

Tags: jquery

Estou numa situação que tenho três elementos numa mesma página.

```
<img class="imagem" />
<img class="imagem" />
<img class="imagem" />
```

Gostaria de selecionar pela classe o segundo elemento desses 3. Como posso fazer isso via jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o seletor [eq(indíce)](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) do jQuery para selecionar um elemento pelo índice do mesmo.

```
var $elemento = $('.imagem:eq(1)');
```

**Veja o exemplo abaixo manipulando o elemento.**

```js
var $elemento = $('.imagem:eq(1)');
$elemento.attr('style', 'border:1px solid red');
```

```css
.imagem {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="imagem" />
<img class="imagem" />
<img class="imagem" />
```

Comment: Lembrando que as vezes dependendo a necessidade da seleção pode se  usar o id, que serve justamente para selecionar elementos específicos e que não existe nenhum outro igual no DOM. O id é tem mais prioridade sobre a class em seleções.

Answer (score 4):

Selecionando pelo índice do elemento, você tem as seguintes opções:

```
$('.imagem')[index];
$('.imagem').get(index);
$('.imagem:eq('+index+')');
```

Obs: Lembrando que o índice começa do zero.